# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - Using glDelete* in onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I want to free textures, buffers and shaders in my android game, if user hit Back button, calls **finish()** method of activity, leading into **onDestroy()**, which i overrided to clean game data, close server connections and so on.
I set **android:launchMode="singleTask"** in my manifest, so calling finish() of activity always leads to destroying right away.
But to use **glDeleteBuffers(...)**, for example, it must be called from thread with EGL context (Renderer thread), but even if set and call such methods from Renderer class, i get - No OpenGL ES context error.

I use NDK, so **NativeLib.*** calls a C/C++ functions like

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL /*class path*/_NativeLib_onDrawFrame(JNIEnv* env, jclass _class)
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 ...
}
```

View

```
public class OGLES2View extends GLSurfaceView
{

  private static class OGLES2Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
  {
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
    {
        NativeLib.onDrawFrame();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
    {
        NativeLib.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig unusedConfig)
    {
        NativeLib.onSurfaceCreated();
    }

    public void onSurfaceDestroy()
    {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Destroying Opengl objects");
        NativeLib.onGLDestroy();//Don't work - call to OpenGL API with current context
    }

}

public OGLES2Renderer renderer = null; 
public OGLES2View(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setRenderer(renderer = new OGLES2Renderer());
}
```

in Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ogles2View = new OGLES2View(this);
    setContentView(ogles2View);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Got finish request for game");
    super.onDestroy();
    ogles2View.render.onSurfaceDestroy(); // Don't not work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the EGL context gets destroyed all the GL buffers etc will get destroyed with it, so this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone *does* need to run something on the GLThread before destroying the `EGLContext` (or at any point in execution outside the given methods), you can use the [`queueEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#queueEvent(java.lang.Runnable)) method of `GLSurfaceView` to post a `Runnable` to the GLThread. Note that you must call `setRenderer()` prior to using `queueEvent()`.

Example (for OP's problem):

```
...

public void onSurfaceDestroy()
{
    queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Destroying Opengl objects");
            NativeLib.onGLDestroy(); //Works since it's called on the GLThread
        }
    }
}

...
```